# Remove multiple double quotes using scala in JSON using regex

Tags: json, regex, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this Json string

{"LAST_NM":**""ILLEGIBLE""**,"FUL_NM":""}

Here is the replace code that I tried to remove the extra double quotes in above Json in scala.But it is not working.

```
replace(":\"\"[a-z]+\"\"",":\"[a-z]+\"")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex capture group by enclosing a regex in ellipses - `(some_regex)`, and then substitute it in the result using `$x` (x=group number). For example:

```
scala> val str = "{\"LAST_NM\":\"\"ILLEGIBLE\"\",\"FULL_NM\":\"\",\"FIRST_NAME\":\"\"NOT_SUPPLIED\"\"}"
str: String = {"LAST_NM":""ILLEGIBLE"","FULL_NM":"","FIRST_NAME":""NOT_SUPPLIED""}

scala> str.replaceAll("\"(\"[^\\,]+?\")\"","$1")
res5: String = {"LAST_NM":"ILLEGIBLE","FULL_NM":"","FIRST_NAME":"NOT_SUPPLIED"}
```